# How to change background color of AppBar Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

This is my code XAML, i just want to change background color of the labels and buttons inside

```
<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <CommandBar Background="#FF3965FF">
        <AppBarButton Label="estação" Icon="Map" Click="Bar_Localizar" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="White" Background="White"/>

        <CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
            <AppBarButton Label="traçar rotas" Icon="Add" Click="bar_tracar_rotas" Foreground="White"/>
            <AppBarToggleButton Label="tráfego"  Checked="ToggleButton_OnChecked" Unchecked="ToggleButton_OnUnchecked"/>
            <AppBarToggleButton Label="mapa aéreo"  Checked="mapa_checked" Unchecked="mapa_unchecked"/>
            <AppBarButton Label="voltar" Icon="Add" Click="bar_voltar"/>
            <AppBarButton Label="Sair" Icon="Add" Click="bar_sair"/>
        </CommandBar.SecondaryCommands>
    </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

I try to use `Foreground="White"` but doesn't works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *AppBar* is system UI and you are not allowed to change colors of individual buttons. If you want you can change the backgrounf color of whole application bar (use *Background* property) and color of all buttons (use *Foreground* property). This should work:

```xml
<Page.BottomAppBar>
  <CommandBar Background="#FF3965FF" Foreground="White">
    <AppBarButton Label="estação" Icon="Map" Click="Bar_Localizar"/>
  </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

Remember also to perform suitable changes for all themes (*Light/Dark/Contrast*) allowed by your app.

If you need something more customizable, then probably you will have to build own control that will mimic the *AppBar*.